# Is it possible to change color theme on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

The site is very light with the white background, and I would like to change to a darker theme.

Does Stack Overflow have this option somewhere? (I've searched for it, but I could not find it..)

Comment: Tanks @Glorfindel, that link was great

Comment: I made a Stack Overflow Dark Theme userscript: https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-overflow-dark-theme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do SO have this option somewhere?

No.

You can use a user stylesheet to override the existing styles. As Glorfindel [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334906/is-it-possible-to-change-color-theme-on-stackoverflow#comment397347_334906), StackApps has a bunch of those around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could only find a theme for super user( http://stackapps.com/questions/3724/super-user-dark-theme) Do you mayby have a link to a stylesheet valid for stack overlow?

Answer (score 11):

Now it is possible and you can [change your theme here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/).

Comment: What about for the other sites -- superuser.com, etc?

Answer (score 2):

There is a userscript written by [Tiny Giant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant) called SODark which is used by some Stack Overflow members to give the site a dark theme:

[SODark.user.js](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/SODark.user.js)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variants of dark themes for SO via Stylish add-on: https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow

Comment: for stylus yes?